# Data not persistent in scikit-learn transformers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'd like to pass additional data to a transformer in scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

class myTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, my_np_array):
        self.data = my_np_array
        print self.data

    def transform(self, X):
        return X

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

data = np.random.rand(20,20)
data2 = np.random.rand(6,6)
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3])

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('myt', myTransformer(data2)), ('randforest', RandomForestClassifier())])
params = {"randforest__n_estimators": [100, 1000]}
estimators = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=params, verbose=True)
estimators.fit(data, y)
```

However, when used in a scikit-learn pipeline, it seems to disappear

I'm getting `None` from the print inside the init method. How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that mydata is not None when you are passing it?

Comment: yes, it is not none

Comment: I guess you should add `.fit` to the estimators for the error to appear.

Comment: yes, thank you. just added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because sklearn handles estimators in a very specific way. In general it will create a new instance of the class for things like grid searching, and will pass a parameters to the constructor. This happens because sklearn has its own **clone** operation ([defined in base.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L29))
which takes your estimator class, gets parameters (returned by `get_params`) and passes it to the constructor of your class

```
klass = estimator.__class__
new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
for name, param in six.iteritems(new_object_params):
    new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
```

In order to support that your object **has to** override `get_params(deep=False)` method, which should return dictionary, which will be passed to constructor

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
class myTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, my_np_array):
        self.data = my_np_array
        print self.data

    def transform(self, X):
        return X

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        return {'my_np_array': self.data}
```

will work as expected.

Comment: that doesn't apply int and float, does it? and do I have to do with all variables local to the instance (self. variable)? I would need it, for example, to get the best estimator

Comment: "doesn't apply int and float"? All I am saying is you need a get_params method, which will provide everything needed to clone instance of your transformer. You can "store" them anywhere you want, get_params needs to return it, but you can have them as static attributes, global variables, whatever you want.

Comment: sorry for bugging you again, but I'm not sure I understood. I don't quite get why parameters are not visible since the purpose of grid search is to try different settings and find the best. How do estimators work in the offical library then? Thank you,

Comment: it is not about visibility. This is how scikit-learn developers decided to go about cloning objects (it has pros and cos, but it is their design decision). Nothing to add here. They (estimators) all implement this interface - they have get_params, which being called - return everything needed to replicate an object. There is also set_param with symmetric meaning etc.